# Reading a yaml configuration file and creating a DAG generator in Airflow 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am new to Airflow 2.0 and really struggling to find a way to save my DAG remotely instead of submitting it in the scheduler automatically. I have a config file which loads settings for my Spark job.

I am trying to write a **utility python file** which reads the configuration file, parses it and creates a DAG file. I have done it using Astronomer's `create_dag` example, but it submits the DAG directly and there's no way for me to see the generated DAG code except for the UI.

1. How can I achieve saving a DAG file instead and submitting later?
2. Also, is it possible for my utility to have some sort of templating that would include the operators and params which I would need to create and save the DAG file remotely so that I can submit it later? (without this I created a sample dag with hardcoded values, but instead I want a utility that would do this for me and save it remotely)
3. Any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to this guide on [Dynamically Generating DAGs in Airflow](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags).

1. One way you can "saving a DAG file" instead of having Airflow dynamically create the DAG is to generate the file beforehand. For example, you can add a step in your CI/CD pipelines to run a script that generates your python file and then push that to the scheduler.
2. This process can be describes as preparing and rendering a template.

   You can use [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/) to accomplish this.

   Fun fact, [Airflow also uses Jinja](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html#templating-with-jinja) to build its webpages as well as allowing the user to leverage jinja templating to render files and parameters!
3. The following example should get you started.

generate_file.py

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os

file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(file_dir))

template = env.get_template('dag.template')

# I don't know what the configuration format but as long as you can convert to a dictionary, it can work.
values = {}

filename = os.path.join(file_dir, 'dag.py')
with open(filename, 'w') as fh:
 fh.write(template.render(
     dag_id="my_dag",
     num_task=2,
     **values
 ))
```

dag.template

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='{{ dag_id }}',
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=datetime(2020, 1, 1)
)

with dag:
    dummy = DummyOperator(
        task_id='test',
        dag=dag
    )
{% for n in range(num_task) %}
    op_{{ loop.index }} = PythonOperator(
        task_id='python_op_{{ loop.index }}',
        dag=dag
    )
{% endfor %}

    op_1 >> op2 >> op3
```

The resulting file dag.py will look like this.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=datetime(2020, 1, 1)
)

with dag:
    dummy = DummyOperator(
        task_id='test',
        dag=dag
    )

    op_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='python_op_1',
        dag=dag
    )

    op_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='python_op_2',
        dag=dag
    )
    
    op_1 >> op2 >> op3
```

Comment: Hi @AlanMa, however 2 questions? What if I had a conf file to load values through the template into the DAG. For example I have a SparkSubmitOperator and all the spark parameters are defined in a conf file. 
And how do I define the task dependencies in this case?
Can you add an edit to your answer and show me an example. And thanks a lot for your help by the way!

Comment: You can write your logic that reads the value from the conf file (with the spark parameters) into generate_file.py. The task dependencies can be write into the task template as is.